# Android tabhost error null pointer tabwidget

Tags: java, android, android-tabhost

Mainactivity:

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TabHost mTabHost;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            mTabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
            setupTab(new TextView(this), "Tab 1");
            setupTab(new TextView(this), "Tab 2");
            setupTab(new TextView(this), "Tab 3");

        }
        private void setupTab(final View view, final String tag) {
            View tabview = createTabView(mTabHost.getContext(), tag);
            TabHost.TabSpec setContent = mTabHost.newTabSpec(tag).setIndicator(tabview).setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory() {

                public View createTabContent(String tag) {return view;}
            });
            mTabHost.addTab(setContent);
        }
        private static View createTabView(final Context context, final String text) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.tabs_bg, null);
            TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tabsText);
            tv.setText(text);
            return view;
        }

    }
```

Activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

<FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

</FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
```

I am experimenting with tabs in order to make a bottom navigation bar without material design library.
How to fix this error? (Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TabWidget.setStripEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference)

Answer (score 3):

You need invoke mTabHost.setup(...);

The reason is your activity does not extends TabActivity, you should invoke TabHost.setup(...) before TabHost.addTab(...) method.

[image]